# Finding the tangent equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the tangent equation hows slop is $1$ and is tangent to $f(x)=18x^5-17$

I have got two tangent function: $y_a=x-17.25$ and $y_b=x-16.73$ can it be?

Answer (score 2):

The graph looks [like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e9lgthg54lm)

The two results likely are tangent lines to each side of the curve, one in the LHP, one in the RHP